# Vue.js multilanguage website with different domains

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, vue.js

I develop a multilanguage website(English and French) with Vue.js. The two versions of the website should have different domains. For example, www.english.com and www.french.com. So, when I click on French version I should be redirected to www.french.com and vice versa.

So, is to possible to generate two "dist" folders in Vue, one for the English version(dist-en) and one for the French(dist-fr)? Or could you help with another solution please, cause I don't wont to duplicate the project folder for the French content?

Thanks!

Comment: How about adding both localizations and using the appropriate one based off of the current domain?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Could you please explain in details?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/dkfbasel/vuex-i18n, it's explained pretty well